# Making specific parts of an image into clickable buttons for android app

Tags: android, imageview, click

(I am an extreme newbie, my knowledge is of basic programming ideas, i.e. a click executes a command, basic cause and effect)

I am wanting to test out a simple idea of having an image (for example sake imagine one page of "Where's Waldo!?") where you open the app and you have an image, (also this is aimed at android tablets) and this image has many details and lots of different focal points going on, so i want the end-user to be able to look through this image and see, (again for example sake) waldo, and then to be able to click on waldo and a text bubble to pop up with "you win!
" or some info about waldo, or any other details on the page.

so far all i have been able to do is make the entire image one button, which is undesirable seeing as i would prefer there to be about 20-30 randomly placed buttons each with their own synopsis of the section of the image being clicked on.

using android app inventor...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clickable area of image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image)

Answer (score 4):

A site explaining how to make specific parts of an image into clickable areas can be found [here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas)...it worked for me..

The link is also summarized at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671342/752843) SO question.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

How about add a small 'Buttons' on the image with transparent background and make sure you add button after image so that it will not be covered by image. Then try and see if you get onClick when you hit button. If this works, may be you can have such multiple buttons over image and user will not notice that he is actually hitting button instead of image.

Answer (score 2):

A button with a transparent background will surely work.

```
<Button 
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="50dip" 
    android:background="#00000000">
</Button>
```